# use layout on private routes react

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-router

im trying to pass a layout to my private routes components but i cannot, the layout is not renderized, and if i use the layout directly, it affect to all routes and not only their childrens.

I have this code, and it apply layout to all routes:

```
    return (
      <Router>
          <OnlyGuest path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>

          <DefaultLayout>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/active-operations" component={ Active } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/pending-operations" component={ Pending } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/approved-operations" component={ Approved } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/to-check-operations" component={ ToCheck } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/rejected-operations" component={ Rejected } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/create-operation" component={OperationCreate} />
          </DefaultLayout>
      </Router>
  );
```

when i do that, how a lot of tutorials says, is not working for me, the layout is not rendered:

```
return (
      <Router>
          <OnlyGuest path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>

          <Route component={DefaultLayout}>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/active-operations" component={ Active } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/pending-operations" component={ Pending } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/approved-operations" component={ Approved } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/to-check-operations" component={ ToCheck } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/rejected-operations" component={ Rejected } />
              <PrivateRoute path="/create-operation" component={OperationCreate} />
          </Route>
      </Router>
  );
```

my PrivateRoute components have this code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        checkAuth() === true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/signin' />
    )} />
);
```

I add the default layout, it retrieve children component for render the routes:

```
export default function DefaultLayout(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
                <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
                    { props.children }
                </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How can i do for the DefaultLayout works in the routes when i want?

Here you can find my actual code, and how is working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-diicmg

You can change isAuth variable to true or false for see the problem. DefaultLayout is always in the screen :c

Comment: Is `DefaultLayout` using `children` to render child components? Please share the code for `DefaultLayout` for further assistance.

Comment: ok, i forgot these, i edit the question with the code.

Comment: Do you mean the following in `PrivateRoute`? `< DefaultLayout><Component {...props} /></DefaultLayout>`. Your issue isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Sorry, my english is bad. When i use <DefaultLayout> <PrivateRoute path="something" component={Something}></DefaultLayout> it is applied to all routes, including the routes that are outside it (only is rendered below), so no matter where you go, it is always there. I want it to only appear on the routes that I want to apply.

Comment: You are saying that if you do something like the following: `<PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} /><DefaultLayout><PrivateRoute path="/active-operations" component={ Active } /></DefaultLayout>`. Where you only wrap `PrivateRoute` with `DefaultLayout` selectively, it applies to all other routes?

Comment: Yes, it is applied to all routes, including those that are not their children, so it breaks all my views by putting the default layout below.

Comment: When you say "children" do you mean a component like `Active` or `ToCheck`? Also, you may need to create a simplified example with a tool such as https://stackblitz.com to help diagnose and resolve this issue.

Comment: ok, i add the code in the question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your implementation (in the StackBlitz) is that multiple routes are being rendered, which is why you are seeing `DefaultLayout` being rendered even if you only wrap select routes with `DefaultLayout`. You can use the [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component to only render a single or set of routes. Without `Switch`, a route like `/` can render multiple routes as described in more detail in the linked documentation:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <OnlyGuest path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
    <DefaultLayout>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    </DefaultLayout>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9p8zqa). Toggle the value of auth to see the `SignIn` renders without `DefaultLayout`.

Hopefully that helps!